# CSS - Style border heading

Tags: css

How do i use css to style a border like this

[image]

Here is my current css

```
header .fixed-header .left h2 {
   font-size: 14px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

but is just make a border at bottom the heading, how do i style a border right like the image above

Comment: have you looked at `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a pseudo element and `transform: skew()`

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2em;
}
h2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```html
<h2>asdf</h2>
```

Comment: @vinnlee you bet :)